# gorilla/sessions fails to save new session when MaxAge is 0

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using gorilla/sessions in a toy app, and I want to use the FilesystemStore, but if I set the `MaxAge` option to 0 for the store, it attempts to remove the session when saving it, but if the session is new, it doesn't have an ID:

```golang
    sess, err := s.store.Get(r, "session-name")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error getting session %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "session", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    sess.Values["name"] = r.FormValue("name")
    if err = sess.Save(r, w); err != nil {
        log.Printf("error saving session %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "saving", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/view", http.StatusFound)
```

And the error I get is:

```
2019/10/15 09:22:03 error saving session remove sessions\session_: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Looking at the Gorilla code, it seems the Gorilla code tries to delete the session from the store before determining if the session has an ID.

Is mine a problem with Gorilla, or with how I'm using it?

Things work fine when not setting `MaxAge` to `0`, but then I'll have to manage the cookies myself.

Comment: It sounds like the file you're using doesn't exist. But you didn't include that part of your code.

Comment: Why are you setting max age to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [`Save` method](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/400b592ab70b9f8ee876cf47bc6c794d255dd4aa/store.go#L210), you'll see that it tries to delete sessions with `MaxAge <= 0`. You actually mark sessions that needs to be removed that way.
Since you're creating session with `s.store.Get(r, "session-name")`, it will use MaxAge from that store, and you should set it to some value bigger than 0.

Doc for setting MaxAge says:

> Individual sessions can be deleted by setting Options.MaxAge
>    = -1 for that session.

But in Save you can see:

> If the Options.MaxAge of the session is <= 0 then the session file
>   will be deleted from the store path.

So, setting it to 0 is the same as setting it -1 or any other negative value.

Comment: Because it tries to delete session that isn't saved yet. MaxAge <= 0 should be used for existing sessions.

Comment: It's not, it deletes only for <= 0. This error occurs when you call Save on new session with MaxAge <=0.

Comment: Right - this is what I'm seeing - I set the `MaxAge` for the store to `0` **because** I want the session cookie to expire when the user closes the browser. However, setting it to 0 tries to delete the file before it has an ID.

Maybe if there were separate options for the session expiration (say, 15 minutes) and setting the cookie so that it does not have an expiration (so it will be removed when the browser closes).

Comment: Try using CookieStore instead of FilesystemStore (with MaxAge = 0).

Comment: Marking this one as the answer - per the API, it's exactly correct. The only remaining problem is that the API uses a cookie to send the session ID, but I can't set the cookie expiration independent of the session expiration - that's the API's fault. (Of course, the documentation does warn that the filesystem store is not fully-baked).